# Determine process name for VirtuaWin rule?

Tags: windows-7, process, virtuawin

I would like to have all windows for a particular application follow a certain rule in VirtuaWin (version 4.4), but I can't figure out a way to do this that is persistent across restarting.

The application giving me trouble is, unfortunately, a proprietary application used within my company, and I don't have a lot of information about the way it works beyond the fact that it's built on `.NET`.

Using Spy++, I can determine the window class for the windows created by this application; it's `WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.<something>`. The `<something>` changes upon system restart. By checking the window class and modifying my VirtuaWin rule, I can get the desired VirtuaWin behavior, but it's annoying to have to open Spy++ every time I do a restart!

I would like to create a rule that uses the process name, but haven't been successful so far. I tried both `<programname>.exe` (which appears to be the process name in the "Processes" list in the task manager) and `<programname>` (without `.exe`), to no avail. Are there any other ways to determine the "process name" that VirtuaWin sees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Process Name is the fully qualified path to the executable. For Example, C:\Windows\Notepad.exe. This should catch your application reliably.

Alternatively, VirtuaWin by default allows you to middle-click a window's title bar to open VirtuaWin's context menu. From there you can add a Window rule, among other things. This won't work with certain programs that use custom windows (in my experience, Firefox is one).

Comment: ...huh. The full path does not appear to work, either, and middle-clicking and selecting "Add Window Rule" shows that the process name for each window is the window name with the first character replaced with `?` (so of course it differs from window to window). I suppose this must be due to some sort of futzing about with window properties in the application itself.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it shows how to determine the process name as seen by `VirtuaWin`, even though the results are disappointing. Thanks for your help.